# How to select a new column contains selected table?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

How to select a new column contains selected table? I try to do it but it return error said (#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row)

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(A+AA+AB+AC+AD+AE+AF+AG+AH+AI+AJ+AK+AL+AM+AN+AO+
        B+C+CL+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+LK+M+N+O+P+Q+R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y+Z) 
        AS SELESAI
        FROM statistik WHERE stastus = '1' GROUP BY kategori ),

SUM(A+AA+AB+AC+AD+AE+AF+AG+AH+AI+AJ+AK+AL+AM+AN+AO+
    B+C+CL+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+LK+M+N+O+P+Q+R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y+Z) 
    AS Jumlah,kategori, 
SUM(A) AS A, 
SUM(AA) AS AA, 
SUM(AB) AS AB, 
SUM(AC) AS AC, 
SUM(AD) AS AD, 
SUM(AE) AS AE, 
SUM(AF) AS AF, 
SUM(AG) AS AG, 
SUM(AH) AS AH, 
SUM(AI) AS AI, 
SUM(AJ) AS AJ, 
SUM(AK) AS AK, 
SUM(AL) AS AL, 
SUM(AM) AS AM, 
SUM(AN) AS AN, 
SUM(AO) AS AO, 
SUM(B) AS B, 
SUM(C) AS C, 
SUM(CL) AS CL, 
SUM(D) AS D, 
SUM(E) AS E, 
SUM(F) AS F, 
SUM(G) AS G, 
SUM(H) AS H, 
SUM(I) AS I, 
SUM(J) AS J, 
SUM(K) AS K, 
SUM(L) AS L, 
SUM(LK) AS LK,
SUM(M) AS M, 
SUM(N) AS N, 
SUM(O) AS O, 
SUM(P) AS P, 
SUM(Q) AS Q, 
SUM(R) AS R, 
SUM(S) AS S, 
SUM(T) AS T, 
SUM(U) AS U, 
SUM(V) AS V, 
SUM(W) AS W, 
SUM(X) AS X, 
SUM(Y) AS Y, 
SUM(Z) AS Z 
FROM statistik WHERE stastus = '4' GROUP BY kategori ;
```

Here's my database:

-- Table structure for table `statistik`

```
CREATE TABLE `statistik` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `kategori` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stastus` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tarikhLaporan` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `A` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AA` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AB` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AC` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AD` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AE` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AF` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AG` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AH` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AI` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AJ` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AK` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AL` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AM` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AN` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `AO` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `B` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `C` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `CL` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `D` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `E` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `F` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `G` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `H` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `I` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `J` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `K` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `L` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `LK` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `M` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `N` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `O` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `P` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Q` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `R` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `S` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `T` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `U` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `V` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `W` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `X` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Y` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Z` int(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

-- Dumping data for table `statistik`

```
INSERT INTO `statistik` (`id`, `kategori`, `stastus`, `tarikhLaporan`, `A`, `AA`, `AB`, `AC`, `AD`, `AE`, `AF`, `AG`, `AH`, `AI`, `AJ`, `AK`, `AL`, `AM`, `AN`, `AO`, `B`, `C`, `CL`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`, `H`, `I`, `J`, `K`, `L`, `LK`, `M`, `N`, `O`, `P`, `Q`, `R`, `S`, `T`, `U`, `V`, `W`, `X`, `Y`, `Z`) VALUES
(8, 'a', 4, '2018-08-17', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(9, 'b', 4, '2018-08-17', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(10, 'b', 1, '2018-08-17', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(11, 'b', 1, '2018-08-17', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(12, 'b', 1, '2018-08-17', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(13, 'b', 1, '2018-08-17', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(14, 'b', 1, '2018-08-17', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(15, 'b', 1, '2018-08-17', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(16, 'bc', 4, '2018-08-17', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(17, 'c', 1, '2018-08-23', 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(18, 'c', 1, '2018-08-23', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(19, 'c', 1, '2018-08-23', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(20, 'z', 4, '2018-08-11', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(21, 'z', 1, '2018-08-11', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(22, '', 1, '0000-00-00', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(23, '', 1, '0000-00-00', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

-- Indexes for dumped tables

-- Indexes for table `statistik`

```
ALTER TABLE `statistik`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `stastus` (`stastus`);
```

-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables

-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `statistik`

```
ALTER TABLE `statistik`
  MODIFY `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=24;
```

Comment: Recommend `TINYINT` instead of `INT`.  The `(2)` means nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top nested select can only return a single value. It shouldnt be a nested query at all. Best to add a case statement to each of your sum

```
(SUM(case when stastus = '1' then A+AA+AB+AC+AD+AE+AF+AG+AH+AI+AJ+AK+AL+AM+AN+AO+
    B+C+CL+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+LK+M+N+O+P+Q+R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y+Z else 0 end) 
    AS SELESAI,
```

and make all the other ones use this format.

```
sum(case when stastus='4' then A else 0 end) as A
```

Otherwise you can refactor using multiple queries you join or union together.

Answer (score 1):

Although I prefer @TomC's approach, you can do what you want with a *correlated* subquery rather than `group by`:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(A+AA+AB+AC+AD+AE+AF+AG+AH+AI+AJ+AK+AL+AM+AN+AO+
        B+C+CL+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+LK+M+N+O+P+Q+R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y+Z) 
                  ) AS SELESAI
        FROM statistik s2
        WHERE s2.status = 1 
              s2.kategori = s.kategori
       ),
       . . .
FROM statistik s
. . .
```